# Internal microphone not working (Retina Macbook pro late 2013)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, microphone

My internal microphone is not working. It picks up sound only when i flick the outer microphone location. When I plug a headphone with a microphone, there is no problem.

I took it to the genius bar and they seemed to think it was hardware related. They quoted me 500 CAD to replace the top case. This was not acceptable.

I think it is not a software problem. But, I cannot be sure. I think the connection between the logic board and dual microphone might be hindered.

I'm using the beta version of OS X yosemite, I wonder if reinstalling the os might fix the problem?

Is there any trouble shooting advice?

Comment: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Microphone+Replacement/23428

Comment: what is "when i flick the outer microphone location"

Comment: on the side. there are two holes. this is where the dual mic is located. if i flick this part of the notebook with my finger I get some feedback through system preferences, sound. Other then that, I get no feedback.

Comment: Sounds like loose connection than. (the cable)

Comment: If I brought it to a non apple authorized computer store, could they do it?